# Java Android. Как реализовать телефонный звонок в фоновом режиме (без activity-звонилки)

Tags: java, android

Как реализовать телефонный звонок в фоновом режиме (без activity-звонилки)

Что писать в методе call()

```
Button getInfo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_info);

    getInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            call();
        }
    });
    
}

public void call() {

}
```

}

Comment: Просто тут не получится, придётся изучать системное API и писать много сложного кода. Попробуйте начать вот с этой доки: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged

Comment: Спасибо, Юрий..